# How to convert the multiple values of a column into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If there is a single value then it should be the key with a null value as a list and if there are multiple values then the first value will be the key and rest will be the list of values in a dictionary.

```
Ex: Column
    ram
    sneha, vijay, harish
    deva
    babu, dominic

Expected o/p:
{
'ram':[],
'sneha': ['vijay', 'harish'],
'deva' : [],
'babu' : ['dominic']

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column data is in the format I described, the below solution gives the expected output

```
dict = {}
cols = [['ram'],['sneha', 'vijay', 'harish'],['deva'],['babu', 'dominic']]
for row in cols:
    dict[row[0]] = [item for item in row[1:len(row)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run a loop to select one row at a time and set 0th index of the row as key and the values following as values in a list.

It can be done like this

```
col = [['ram'], ['sneha', 'vijay', 'harish'], ['deva'], ['babu', 'dominic']]

out = {}

for row in col:
    out[row[0]] = [x for x in row[1 : len(row)]]

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
columns_list = [['ram'], ['sneha', 'vijay', 'harish'],
                ['deva'], ['babu', 'dominic']]

result = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in columns_list}

print(result)
# {'ram': [], 'sneha': ['vijay', 'harish'], 'deva': [], 'babu': ['dominic']}
```

If input is `string` then you can do like this:

```
rows = '''ram
sneha, vijay, harish
deva
babu, dominic'''
columns_list = [row.split(',') for row in rows.split("\n")]
# if columns have space at begin and end then `strip` them
columns_list = tuple(map(lambda cols: [c.strip() for c in cols], columns_list))
print(columns_list)
# (['ram'], ['sneha', 'vijay', 'harish'], ['deva'], ['babu', 'dominic'])
result = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in columns_list}
print(result)
# {'ram': [], 'sneha': ['vijay', 'harish'], 'deva': [], 'babu': ['dominic']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source data is a string object then

```
data = ["ram", "sneha, vijay, harish", "deva", "babu, dominic"]
res = {}
for i in data:
    val = i.split(",")
    res[val[0]]= list(map(str.strip, val[1:]))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'babu': ['dominic'], 'deva': [], 'ram': [], 'sneha': ['vijay', 'harish']}
```